# list index out of range in while loop

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to implemnt Minesweeper game , but i'm stuck , i'm getting the list out of range error and i don't where i did wrong

```
def Int_jeu(largeur,longueur,diff):
global n, m,T
dif = diff

n=largeur
m=longueur
T = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)]


d=((n*m)*dif)//100
print(len(T[0]))
for i in  range(d):
    a=random.randint(0,len(T)-1)
    b=random.randint(0,len(T[0])-1)


    while (T[a][b] == "2"):

        a=random.randint(0,n-1)
        b=random.randint(0,m-1)

    T[a][b] = "2"


return(T)
```

this is the line where i got the error

```
  while (T[a][b] == "2"):
```

i have declared the matrix T out of the int_jeu function

```
T = []
```

can anyone explain me why i get the error please.

Comment: replace between `n` and `m` in the random functions. `a` is the rows index which corresponds to the `m` parameter and `b` is the column index which corresponds to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

`m` is your first dimension, `n` is your second, but `a` is used to index the first dimension (`m`) while being derived from `n` (same for `b`, in reverse).

Change:

```
    a=random.randint(0,n-1)
    b=random.randint(0,m-1)
```

to:

```
    a=random.randint(0,m-1)  # Or to simplify, random.randrange(m)
    b=random.randint(0,n-1)  # Or to simplify, random.randrange(n)
```

to fix.